# Google NDB - required property inside StructuredProperty's structure not working as expected

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have encountered an issue with the required option from ndb.Model when it is placed inside a Model specified as a structure from a StructuredProperty.

Here is the models definition :

```
class SubModel(ndb.Model):
    submodel_id = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)


class MyModel(ndb.Model):

    model_id = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    submodels = ndb.StructuredProperty(SubModel, repeated=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'submodels' in kwargs.keys():
            _submodels = []
            for kwarg in kwargs['submodels']:
                if isinstance(kwarg, SubModel):
                    _submodels.append(kwarg)
                else:
                    t = SubModel(**kwarg)
                    _submodels.append(t)
            self.submodels = _submodels
```

What I want to do is either to create a model with no submodels or to create a model in which every submodels have a required id, otherwise, it raises an error.

So when I test this model, I get these results :

```
args1 = {"model_id":"some_id","submodels":[{"submodel_id":null}]}
model1 = MyModel(**args1)
model1.put()
print model1.key.id()

# Everything works while submodel_id hasn't been set and it returns the key id from Google Datastore

args2 = {"model_id":null,"submodels":[{"submodel_id":"some_id"}]}
model2 = MyModel(**args2)
model2.put()
print model2.key.id()

# Google Datastore raises an error : Entity has uninitialized properties: model_id
```

Is this behavior standard behavior from ndb.StructuredProperty (meaning that no property options are considered from the structure specified) or should I implement what I want to do differently ?

What I also want to do is to make Submodel inherit from ndb.Expando instead of ndb.Model but since ndb.Expando inherits from ndb.Model, that would be an even more precise question...

Answer (score 0):

You have `required = True` on 'model_id'.  You are trying to `put()` an entity without defining one  (`null` doesn't count).

Your `put()`s are on `MyModel`.  Not sure why the `submodel_id` requirement in `SubModel`  isn't being checked when `putting` on the parent model. Seems it should be checked.  Can you check the datastore and see what has actually been `put()`?  When you read back that entity, what do you get?

Comment: This is what I would get. In this screenshot, only the entity with the id "5390493194125312" is unwanted.
[Google Datastore screenshot](https://imgur.com/K4V0zLE)

Comment: OK, so I was addressing the `Entity has uninitialized properties: model_id` error.  That is because you tried to put an entity without a required property.  To check for required property in a `StructuredProperty`, looks like you'll have to run your own checking before putting.